# Download count of GitHub release in R

Tags: r, download, count, github-api

I am trying to get the [download count](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-the-download-count-for-your-releases/) of a public repo using the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/) and R v3.1.2. Using the public [samples repo](https://github.com/googlesamples) from Google I have the following:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

url <- "https://api.github.com/repos/googlesamples/google-services/downloads"
response <- GET(url)
json <- content(response, "text")
json <- fromJSON(json)

print(json)
```

However, I noticed that json returns an empty list. Is it because there are no releases in this public repo? The goal is to determine how many times this repo has been downloaded by the public -- or any other public repo for that matter. Is this even possible?

Comment: If there are no releases there is no current github API endpoint that gets the download count for arbitrary files. Use the endpoint against https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/releases and you'll get the count

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The old Github download counts [have been deprecated](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads) and don't seem to work any longer. You can get download counts from releases, but it does take a little bit of manipulation:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

url <- "https://api.github.com/repos/allenluce/mmap-object/releases"
response <- GET(url)
json <- content(response, "text")
json <- fromJSON(json)
print(Reduce("+", lapply(json$assets, function(x) sum(x$download_count))))
```

There are some caveats:

1. The repo must have releases.
2. The releases must have files
3. There is no API to obtain the count of people who have cloned your repo.

Github allows you to count the number of released files that have been downloaded, but that's about it. The google-services repo that you use as an example has neither releases nor files!

Comment: @doug_luce this is good! I cloned the https://github.com/allenluce/mmap-object repo in Terminal and then I downloaded the repo zip via Chrome, but the count is still the same (49). When does the number change?

Comment: It does change, now I see 50 downloads. They must do this on a batch basis, I remember reading something about performance problems when updating counts with their previous rendition.

Comment: Confirmed! That appears to be the case. I appreciate everyone's input but your response is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries, hope it helps and thanks for the bounty!

Comment: @doug_luce sorry to insist but I dowloaded the zip of your mma-object repo via Chrome and then cloned your project via Terminal but the count did not move. What action did you do to make the download release number increase? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Turns out that Github only lets you get download counts for release *assets* and not for the downloads of the full repo itself (i.e the zip and tar.gz files associated with a release). Clone stats are available with authenticated scraping (https://gist.github.com/dougluce/1956acf8d35e42aab3f2) but it doesn't look like this information is available for public repos in general.

Answer (score 1):

The API mentioned in "[Get a single release](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-single-release)" is:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:id
```

As commented, you need to apply it against releases of a repo.
As an example, here is a [python gist](https://gist.github.com/Hanse00/9674972#file-release_downloads-py) (by [**Philip Hansen** - `Hanse00`](https://github.com/Hanse00)) which extracts the `download_count`.
(not in R, but to show how the  `/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:id` url is used)

Extract:

```py
#Iterate through every tag
search_point = 0
while formatted_string.find("tag_name", search_point) != -1:
    #Find where in the string the tag and download texts are
    find_point = formatted_string.find("tag_name", search_point)
    download_point = formatted_string.find("download_count", find_point)
```

Here is an [even shorter script](https://gist.github.com/chapmanb/7631323) by [**Brad Chapman** `chapmanb`](https://github.com/chapmanb), using [`sigmavirus24/github3.py`](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py) (Python library for interfacing with the GitHub APIv3):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Get download stats for releases from GitHub.
Needs development version of github3.
pip install github3
pip install git+https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py.git
"""
import github3

repo = github3.repository("chapmanb", "bcbio.variation")
for release in repo.iter_releases():
    for asset in release.iter_assets():
        print release.name, asset.name, asset.download_count
```

(You have [many](https://gist.github.com/gwatts/1131e0a69522ddd4cd99) [more](https://gist.github.com/WrinklyNinja/d26b2f65ff83ba2ce40a) [examples](https://gist.github.com/fooforge/137779a229db5ffe2482))